# How do I find the value of chi_square of alpha 0.05 and degree of freedom of 1 in R?

Tags: r

This is what I currently have:

```
alpha <- 0.05
dchisq(1-alpha, df=1)
```

But I'm not entirely sure if it's correct.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the *critical value* for a given alpha and df for the chi-squared distribution, you should use

```
qchisq(1-alpha, df=1)
```

or

```
qchisq(alpha, lower.tail=FALSE, df=1)
```

(the latter will be more accurate for alpha <<1)

for `alpha=0.05`, this is 3.841459 (which is confirmed by [this web page](https://mathbench.umd.edu/modules/statistical-tests_chisquare_advanced/page14.htm))